# Java Console Standalone?

Tags: java, swing, jar, console, jframe

I made a simple `JFrame` in java. But I also want to have like a developer console open at the same time you open the real .jar file. On the 8th line is the text I want to output in the console window that should start next the `JFrame`.

Code:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Launcher extends JFrame {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Launcher().setVisible(true);
        System.out.println("Started Launcher...");
    }
    private Launcher() {
        super("DevCity13 - Launcher (Alpha)");
        setSize(600, 600);
        setResizable(false);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can always display your own console which outputs the content of whatever is written to System.out:

[image]

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.PrintStream;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Launcher extends JFrame {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private static class Console {
        private final JFrame frame;

        public Console() {
            frame = new JFrame();
            final JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(24, 80);
            textArea.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
            textArea.setForeground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
            textArea.setFont(new Font(Font.MONOSPACED, Font.PLAIN, 12));
            System.setOut(new PrintStream(new OutputStream() {

                @Override
                public void write(int b) throws IOException {
                    textArea.append(String.valueOf((char) b));
                }
            }));
            frame.add(textArea);
        }

        public void init() {
            frame.pack();
            frame.setVisible(true);
        }

        public JFrame getFrame() {
            return frame;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Console console = new Console();
                console.init();
                Launcher launcher = new Launcher();
                launcher.setVisible(true);
                console.getFrame().setLocation(
                        launcher.getX() + launcher.getWidth()
                                + launcher.getInsets().right, launcher.getY());
                System.out.println("Started Launcher...");
            }
        });
    }

    private Launcher() {
        super("DevCity13 - Launcher (Alpha)");
        setSize(600, 600);
        setResizable(false);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, This is kinda accurate! The only thing I want to know is if there is a way to give the console a Title, if you know that? Thanks for the code man btw! :)

Comment: @valrossen_Oliver just call `setTitle("Some title")` on the frame of the console.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to enable the Java console when you run a `.jar`. To do so, follow the steps on the official documentation [here](http://www.java.com/en/download/help/javaconsole.xml). It may change a little bit depending on your Operating System, but that is the idea.

Comment: That was not quite the thing I needed, you see... I want the end user that open the .Jar file to get an Console (like the windows cmd) where it prints the text on line 8... IS there a way for that?

Comment: If you are not willing to implement your own console, I don't see another way. You could create another `JFrame` with a `JTextField` and  display your console messages. In this case, you would have to change the `System.out` to something else in order to store and present those messages on the new `JFrame`.